# What version of iPhoto for Mac OS 10.4

Tags: macos, iphoto, osx-tiger

What version of iPhoto would I need to run on Mac OS 10.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhoto is part of [iLife](http://www.apple.com/ilife/). According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta27615), you can run iLife 06 and iLife 08 on Mac OS X 10.4.